# How to declare a path of file in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I'm going to do something like this,

```
If txt1.Text = "A" And txt2.Text = "B" Then
"path of my file which name is = c:/A.B"
End If

If txt1.Text = "C" And txt2.Text = "D" Then
"path of my file which name is = c:/C.D"
End If
```

How I'm going to do something like this ? I'm using vb.net

Comment: Shouldn't the path use a backslash (`\`) instead of a forward slash ('/')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach would be to use  Path.Combine.

Declare a function first:

```
Private Function CreatePath(ByVal fileName As String,
                            ByVal extension As String) As String

    Return Path.Combine("C:\", fileName & "." & extension)

End Function
```

Then call this wherever needed.

```
Dim Path as string

If txt1.Text = "A" And txt2.Text = "B" Then
     "path of my file which name is = c:/A.B"
     Path = CreatePath("A", "B")
End If

If txt1.Text = "C" And txt2.Text = "D" Then
   "path of my file which name is = c:/C.D"
   Path = CreatePath("C", "D")
End If
```

Comment: ok then if I declare that one first where should i call that function ?

Comment: Check the edit. I have declared a function and used it in your scenario.

Comment: if I want to search that file by using file open function how I'm going to do that ? If let say I insert A and B and how I'm going to read that content of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `String.Format` method to concatenate them together.

```
Dim path As String = String.Format("c:/{0}.{1}", txt1.Text, txt2.Text)
```

Function:

```
Private Function ConPath(a As String, b As String) As String
  Return String.Format("c:/{0}.{1}", a, b)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by simply writing this

```
"path of my file which name is = c:\" & txt1.Text & "." & txt2.Text
```